# What does "Full practice day" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, adjectives

This context comes from the movie "Five Easy Pieces"

> BOBBY-What're you doing right now...
> CATHERINE-Right now I'm going to run a hot tub and soak myself.
> BOBBY-Then after that?
> CATHERINE-After that, I plan to read some music and rest for a while.
> BOBBY-Tomorrow, then.
> CATHERINE-Tomorrow's a **full** practice day...  But the day after is kind of open.

**"[full](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Full)"** at TheFreeDictionary.com:

> 5. **(often with of or with)** bursting, packed, teeming, abounding, jammed, swarming *A day full of entertainment.*

If it says "**often with of or with**" then it means that it sometimes occurs without it. Does the sentence mean essentially "Tomorrow's a day full of practice"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means a day full of practice. It also has the connotation that she will practice all the aspects of whatever craft she is practicing.

In a sport that might mean exercises and drills as well as a practice game. For a musician it might mean scales as well as work on the pieces she is preparing to perform.

Comment: She's a musician. She has to spend the whole day practicing.